# Algorithmical issue with point inside circle

Tags: algorithm, dictionary

I have a question [ silly - I admit ] about finding wherether the point is in the circle or not, I have a coordinates of the center of circle, and I know the equation, but I'm having the problem with radius, let say it is 2 km, so I have x:46.123654 y: 15.789456 and r=2 or 200 or 2000? What should be the value of R?

Comment: This is completely unanswerable with the current information - the value of R will depend on the scale. If the real world distance between the points (0,0) and (0,1) is 1km, R would be 2; if the difference is 1m, R would be 2000; etc.

Comment: What are the units of x and y?  kilometers, decameters, or meters?

Comment: hey what my question got -2. Thank u Anthony Grist

Comment: Your question got -3, because it is not clear what you are asking for. As stated, value for `R` might be absolutely anything, for example "elephant", because you didn't say what `R` is. You see, different people and different textbooks use *different* variable names, so you always have to define your variables. Also the values somewhat suggest that you are speaking of geodesic coordinates, which is altogether different can of worms compared to simple Cartesian system that is implied by your use of `x` and `y`.

Comment: well I thought r for radius is an international shortcut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, the units of `r` should almost certainly be the same as the units of `x` and `y`.  If, for instance `x = 46.123654` means 46.123654 *meters*, and the radius of your circle is two *kilometers*, then the value of `r` should be `2000.0`, meaning two thousand *meters*. You should also be explicit in some comment about what the units are, i.e. `x = 46.123654 //meters`. If the units are the same, you can apply formulas without confusing conversions, for instance:

```
//determines whether a point (x, y) is in the circle of radius r centered at (0, 0)
bool isInCircle(double x, double y, double r)
{
    return x * x + y * y <= r * r; //pythagorian theorem!
}
```

This isn't really programming, just middle-school math and common sense.